# How to prevent data loss when I want to update database by using db-migration?

Tags: database, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, database-migration

When I was making update my database by using db-migration, I faced a problem that was

```
Automatic migration was not applied because it would result in data loss.
```

(I used `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` such as `[Required]` and `[StringLength(25)]` for some properties. For example `Title` property.)

I know if I set the `AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed` to `true` and `Update-Database -Force`, my database will be update but my data will be removed and I'm going to prevent from it. I want to protect my data.

I've used Entity Framework 6.x

How can I solve this problem?

***Configuration class:***

```
namespace Jahan.Blog.Web.Mvc.Migrations
{
   using System;
   using System.Data.Entity;
   using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
   using System.Linq;

   internal sealed class Configuration 
    : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Jahan.Blog.Web.Mvc.Models.JahanBlogDbContext>
   {
       public Configuration()
       {
           AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
           AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
       }

       protected override void Seed(Jahan.Blog.Web.Mvc.Models.JahanBlogDbContext context)
       {

       }
   }
}
```

***Initial class:***

```
namespace Jahan.Blog.Web.Mvc.Migrations
{
   using System;
   using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

   public partial class Initial : DbMigration
   {
       public override void Up()
       {
       }

       public override void Down()
       {
       }
   }
}
```

***My DbContext:***

```
namespace Jahan.Blog.DataAccess
{
   public class JahanBlogDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, int, UserLogin, UserRole,    UserClaim>
   {
       public JahanBlogDbContext()
           : base("name=JahanBlogDbConnectionString")
       {

       }
       protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>().HasRequired(t => t.Article).WithMany(t => t.Comments).HasForeignKey(d => d.ArticleId).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().ToTable("Role");
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>().ToTable("UserRole");
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin");
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaim");
       }
       // ... codes ....
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add sql to fix the data in a way that is acceptable to you. You need to ensure that the alter statements generated BY EF do not cause data loss.

Use the `Sql` method in a migration to run your own sql:

```
public override void Up()
{
    //Add this to your migration...
    Sql("UPDATE dbo.Table SET Name = LEFT(Name, 25) WHERE LEN(Name) > 25")

    //...before the code generated by EF
    AlterColumn("dbo.Table", "Name ", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 25));
}
```

Comment: Please specify where I should add this code? in which file?

Comment: You should put this in the `Up` method of the migrations file generated when you add a migration, which you must do after making any changes to the Model. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591621

Comment: Your comment was useful and my database be updated.(I see database in SqlServer and it was OK)But I got an error when the program is running......
The model backing the 'JahanBlogDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

Comment: I deleted records of __MigrationHistory table from database .my program run successfully, now!

Comment: If I want to determine a range of value for a field in database by using db-migration, what should be done?
...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26493019/determining-the-range-of-value-for-a-field-in-database-by-using-db-migration