# How can I change data type of a column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, database-migration

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I want to change the data type of a column (`Size`) from `decimal` to `int`. First, I used designer of SQL Server but SQL Server did not allow me to do it. Please attention to the picture.

Then I decided to write a script. But I got an error.

1. How can I do it by using a SQL script?
2. How can I do it by db-migration?

   I've used Entity Framework 6.x, C# and code-first approach for creating database. I want to preserve my data in `Tag` table.
3. Is there better tool than db-migration? I think it's boring!

My model:

```
namespace Jahan.Blog.Model
{
   public class Tag : Entity, ITag
   {
    [Range(1, 4)]
    public virtual int Size { get; set; } //In db data type of Size is decimal.I want to change it to int.

    [Required]
    [StringLength(25)]
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }

    [StringLength(256)]
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public virtual ISet<ArticleTag> ArticleTags { get; set; }       // FK

    public virtual ISet<ProjectTag> ProjectTags { get; set; }       // FK
   }
}
```

[image]

SQL script:

```
USE [Jahan-Blog]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Tag]    Script Date: 10/23/2014 16:17:09 ******/
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Tag]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Tag]
GO

USE [Jahan-Blog]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Tag]    Script Date: 10/23/2014 16:17:09 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tag](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Size] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Tag] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

I got this error after running the script.

> Msg 3726, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Could not drop object 'dbo.Tag'
>   because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
>
> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 2
>   There is already an object named 'Tag' in the
>   database.

DbMigrations configuration:

```
namespace Jahan.Blog.Web.Mvc.Migrations
{
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
using System.Linq;

//For knowing more information about db-migration please visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591621
internal sealed class Configuration 
    : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Jahan.Blog.Web.Mvc.Models.JahanBlogDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(Jahan.Blog.Web.Mvc.Models.JahanBlogDbContext context)
    {
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Add a column called  NewSize, update the NewSize column's values based on the current column Size, drop the column Size, rename NewSize to Size. No table dropping is needed.

Comment: I think that `alter table Tag alter column [Size] int` should for example do. You mays also want to play with `not null` and `default value`.

Comment: @SpectralGhost: If I do it, I will lose my data in Size column.
I need them.

Comment: Which is why the second step was to update the NewSize field

Comment: @SpectralGhost: Can you help me about this question...
http://stackoverflow.com/q/26493019/1817640

Comment: @Jahan Sorry, I'm not up on EF syntax and usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the type with SQL run the following

```
Alter table dbo.[Tag] alter column [Size] int NOT NULL
```

To change the type through an EF migration use

```
AlterColumn("dbo.Tag", "Size", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
```

Comment: Where I have to run this command? In Package manager Console of visual studio or ?

Answer (score 1):

To be able to make your changes in SQL Server designer, on the Tools menu, click Options, expand
Designers, and then click Table and Database Designers. 
Clear the Prevent saving changes that require the table to be
re-created check box.